# How can I contract an email tracking service and be silent about it?

Tags: email, smtp, user-tracking, dns-domain, tracking

I use a customized e-mail and my web-master, who is also the domain owner,  doesn't allow me to see the settings that the DNS provides. Some DNS services provide, beside domain name registration, services like free forwarding email. Since it is possible to set up more than one e-mail to be forwarded, I'm suspicious that my webmaster is forwarding the messages addressed to myname@company.com to hisemail@hismail.com and competing with me. I installed an e-mail tracking service called [bananatag](http://bananatag.com/gmail/) and did not predict that it would send me a lot of welcoming messages and blablas. So now I'm quite afraid that my web-master is aware that I'm tracking the emails and he'll take some countermeasures like this [How can I protect against email tracking services?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30961/how-can-i-protect-against-email-tracking-services).

Back to my question: Is there another way to know which are the computers opening the messages addressed to my account?

Comment: See DNS settings? DNS is (mostly) public, and you can just look them up using a tool like dig.

and the forward is only possible if a MTA is configured for such a use, which is easier to do for a full domain than a specific user. I fail to see how this forward would be competing with you, The Best solution I can think of is to implement encrypted mail, so that you and only you can read your mail. you need the people that mail you however be aware of this and have them send the mail encrypted to you.

Comment: Actually I got confused because I discovered that Godaddy™ offers free email forwarding service besides the domain registration. Since I manage my DNS settings and this free forwarding service at the same place at first I thought they're both the same thing. I'll edit the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Email servers store all mails they forward in cleartext. That means you must trust your email service provider to not snoop on you. An automatic forwarder is not necessary to do that. There are other ways to forward the content of your emails without using email. Also, all email tracking solutions depend on cooperation of the email reader. Most email readers can be configured in ways which make it impossible to track when an email is viewed in them (for example by not loading any images embedded in an email).

When you can not trust the provider, either switch to a different one or convince your communication partners to use an end-to-end encryption system like PGP.

Comment: "Email servers store all mails they forward in cleartext." Is this possible to have access to that data? 
By email servers do you mean the one on this [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mail_server_software)? Please check out my edit on the question because it might be plainer than before.

Comment: Paulo - as to your core question: no, you cannot know if anyone has read your email. Philipp covers this.